# Subclassed UILabel stored within serialized view not storing custom vars

Tags: ios, uiview, uilabel, nscoding

So, I have a view that is being serialized and stored in a file. Within that view, is *n* subclassed UILabels, with the only difference being a *live* property. I have the initwithcoder and encodewithcoder within the UILabel subclass, but I am still unable to get the custom variable within the label. I have included my subclass' methods and the below. Any help is appreciated.

Custom UILabel:

```
- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:decoder];

    if (self != nil) {
        self.live = [decoder decodeBoolForKey:@"live"];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
    [aCoder encodeBool:self.live forKey:@"live"];
}
```

Because I am only unarchiving the view, which contains the labels within, I assume that ios does not unarchive the custom labels?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to serialize a view. The proper thing to do would be to serialize the variables (maybe in a plist) and then instantiate the view when you need it later.

Comment: Please show the code that archives / unarchives the label from the outside, if you know what I mean. Also, you are missing a call to super encodeWithCoder.

Comment: And, unsurprisingly, that is what I was missing, thank you. All is working now. The unarchiver, simply grabs the bytes from the file and loads the view from the data. @jrturton, if you add that as an answer, I will mark it as correct and commend you as such. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a call to `[super encodeWithCoder:aCoder]`. This will result in an incorrectly serialised object, I'm not sure what the consequences are, but you seem to have found one of them!

Comment: it seems the consequences are that it returns an object but only with what I chose to deserialize and none of that fancy stuff apple has put into labels etc. Cheers